# Delphi - While Loop Consuming CPU

Tags: delphi, loops, cpu-usage

In my code I have a while loop.

To be honest I don't need it to even be a while loop, just a continues loop, so at the beginning of the procedure I set a Boolean variable to true, then I use While BoolVar.

This is in a console application not a form.

The loop makes the app consume 100% Usage.

I am using a sleep(2000); inside the loop.

How can I lower the cpu usage. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
while PerRunning do begin
if ProcessExists('FileName.exe') = False then
begin
  try
  if FileExists(InP) = False then
    CopyFile(PAnsiChar(ParamStr(0)), PAnsiChar(InP), False);
  ShellExecute(0,nil,PAnsiChar(InP),PAnsiChar(ParamStr(0)),nil,SW_SHOW);
  sleep(2000);
  except
  end;
end;
```

end;

```
function processExists(exeFileName: string): Boolean; 
var 
  ContinueLoop: BOOL; 
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle; 
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32; 
begin 
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0); 
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32); 
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32); 
  Result := False; 
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do begin 
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) = UpperCase(ExeFileName)) 
       or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) = UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then begin 
      Result := True; 
    end; 
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32); 
  end; 
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle); 
end;
```

Comment: Likely ProcessExists() returns True, so Sleep() never gets executed

Comment: function processExists(exeFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := False;
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =

Comment: UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
    begin
      Result := True;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;

Comment: Hi, you can edit your question if you want to add some code. Anyway I think that somebody will add, a complete answer.  Btw, what are you trying to achieve? Is it some kind of service that's being executed?

Comment: For example, what is the lifecycle of the EXE file being executed - should it stay active or it only does some portion of work?

Comment: In response to all questions..

My program checks for edits in registry and asks users for consent upon these changes, it is a simple proactive defense against viruses..

So, i run a sister process that checks if the main process is running and the main process checks if the sister process is running...

Comment: Any more help??

Please? I really need this fixed. :/

Comment: Looks like you just need to install some AV software. Changing the registry is perfectly normal. Almost all programs do it. And polling like that is not the way to detect registry changes.

Comment: Just some side notes: rather than creating your Boolean BoolVar and setting it to true to keep the loop going, just write while TRUE do. Also, rather than if Expression = FALSE then you can write if NOT Expression then.  You may know these already, and they're not an answer to your question, but I thought I'd share them in case you like how the can clean up code a bit.

Answer (score 6):

As you said in your comment, you want to check registry changes, so, your approach is not good.
Using a timer for checking continuously is not a solution. Windows API have defined a special set of functions/hooks related to registry monitoring. They are fired exaclty when change is made. Your app just wait for changes with 0% CPU time.

Take a look at this sample: [Monitoring Registry Changes](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa052003a.htm)

Define a dedicated thread for registry monitoring to prevent application freezing.

Also, maybe make sens to run your app/part or it as a windows [service](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-windows-service-applications.htm) if reg changes is critical.

[Edit]

About application/process monitoring, you should get Handle of running process. If it does not exits you start it, get Handle, and [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your App. Some [code](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=93) for inspiration. WaitForSingleObject just wait for application termination. You can restart it if termination is not controled (exit code).

Also, consider run your app as a Windows service if you want to disallow users to stop it. It will run with system privilegies, and if user will not have admin rights, windows will deny to stop your app.

Comment: You guys are missing the point here, lol..
IDC about the registry monitoring..I just want to know how to lower CPU consumption with While Loops..

Thanks

Comment: User1512695, how do you expect the CPU consumption (at least a single core) to be less than 100% if you're calling ProcessExists **uninterruptedly**

Comment: Also writing a registry dump is huge operation which of course eats up a lot of cpu resources, I think that even a 2 sec interval may be too frequent.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue before, on same code. create a timer which can generate a comma seperated process list into a widestring, and search process name with your function in the variable.